# How to search a cell array in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

My program asking the user to rent and return movies.  I have a list of movies made in excel and have the program load and read them.  The user has a choice of 'rent' or 'return'.  If they are renting the program randomly picks a movie that is stored in the excel.  From here i want to change the available from yes to no if they chose to rent that one.  How can i do that?

If the user chooses return i ask to enter the movie name.  How can i search the excel to find the column the movie is in to change the available from no to yes?  Also i want the user to be able to rent the movie watched.  This is all i have for that section:

```
 [num text raw] = xlsread('all_movies.xlsx');
 prompts = {'What movie are you retunring?'};
 returning = inputdlg(prompts);
 strcell = (text);
 strfind(strcell)
```

Answer (score 0):

add a column to your excel file indication availability status (e.g. 0 is available, 1 is rented). that should help with the first step.

second step: when you search for the movie, use [strcmpi](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strcmpi.html), which will give you a logical vector with 1 indicating the array location, thus which row in your Excel file that has that movie title

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered storing the movies as a `struct`? each movie is a `fieldname` in the struct and the values for each field would be whether it is rented or not, etc.

See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html) how to use string variables to access fields of structs.